# $\lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2}\right)$

Tags: limits, lacunary-series

Has anybody seen (or can anybody come up with) a proof that 
 $$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2}\right) = \alpha$$ 
for all $\alpha > 0$?

And also that 
 $$\lim_{\alpha\to 0^+} \left[ \lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\alpha -  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2}\right)}{1-x}
\right]=\frac16$$

I thought I had a proof of the first limit but it was flawed.

**EDIT** I had written the wrong expression for the second of the limits.  It is now corrected.

Comment: From $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+a)^{-s} \Gamma(s/2) = 2\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{- (n+a)^2 x^2}dx$ and inverse Mellin/Laplace we get that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{- (n+a)^2 x^2} \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{x}$ as $x \to 0$ . Otherwise, the Poisson summation applied to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{- (n+a)^2 x}$ should give the same result.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps with the first statement. The exponentiation involved in the question is for a number just below 1 raised to what quickly become high powers, so how is the pole at $x=0$ important?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula), we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^K (x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2})&=\int_0^K (e^{y^2\log(x)}-e^{(y+\alpha)^2\log(x)})\,dy\\\\
&+\frac{e^{-K^2|\log(x)|}-e^{-(K+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}-(1-e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|})}2  \\\\
&+\log(x)\int_0^K \left(2ye^{-y^2|\log(x)|}-2(y+\alpha)e^{-(y+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}\right)P_1(y)\,dy \\\\
&=\int_0^\alpha e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}\,dy-\int_K^{K+\alpha}e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}\,dy\\\\
&+\frac{e^{-K^2|\log(x)|}-e^{-(K+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}-(1-e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|})}2  \\\\
&+\log(x)\int_0^K \left(2ye^{-y^2|\log(x)|}-2(y+\alpha)e^{-(y+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}\right)P_1(y)\,dy \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit as $K\to \infty$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2})&=\int_0^\alpha e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}\,dy
-\frac{1-e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|}}2  \\\\
&+\log(x)\int_0^\infty \left(2ye^{-y^2|\log(x)|}-2(y+\alpha)e^{-(y+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}\right)P_1(y)\,dy  \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Taking the limit as $x\to 1^-$ in $(2)$ yields the coveted result

$$\lim_{x\to ^-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2})=\alpha$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: The asymptotical expansion $$\psi(x)=\log(x)-\frac{1}{2x}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{B_{2n}}{2n x^{2n}}$$ is usually derived from the EMC formula, so I guess our solutions are not that different. (+1) and happy new year.

Comment: I assume here that $P_1(x) = (x-\lfloor x \rfloor) - 1$.  I like this one better than Jack's just because I could not work out his computation of the last series via the digamma function, while I could follow your reasoning.

Comment: @MarkFischler Mark, you are correct regarding $P_1(x)$.  And Happy New Year!  - Mark

Answer (score 7):

If we set $x=e^{-t}$ we have to prove that
$$ \lim_{t\to 0^+}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(e^{-tk^2}-e^{-t(k+\alpha)^2}\right) = \alpha.$$
As a function of $t$, the above series is regular enough to make us able to state:
$$ \lim_{t\to 0^+}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(e^{-tk^2}-e^{-t(k+\alpha)^2}\right) = \lim_{m\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}me^{-mt}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(e^{-tk^2}-e^{-t(k+\alpha)^2}\right)\,dt$$
(we use $me^{-mt}$ as an approximation of the Dirac delta distribution) and the original limit is converted into:
$$ \lim_{m\to +\infty}\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{m}{m+k^2}-\frac{m}{m+(k+\alpha)^2}\right)=\lim_{m\to +\infty}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{m(2\alpha k+\alpha^2)}{(m+k^2)(m+(k+\alpha)^2)}$$
Now the last series can be computed through the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and the limit as $m\to +\infty$ is exactly $\alpha$ as wanted, since:
$$\frac{i}{2}\left[\psi(\alpha-im)-\psi(\alpha+im)\right] = \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\tfrac{1}{2}-\alpha}{m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right). $$
The second question is essentially equivalent to finding an extra term in the previous asymptotic expansion.

Comment: Nice answer. (+1)

Comment: I really like the idea of introducing the approximation-to-the-identity. (+1)

Comment: Happy New Year Jack.  Great solution.  (+1) I took a different approach and applied the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.  -Mark

Comment: I don't see that this gives $\frac16$ for the second limit (but I had written it wrong, so unless you were a mind reader, you probably could not have attacked that part of the problem. At any rate, I would imagine your technique could be brought to bear, but I am not strong enough to see how. I will ask the second part in a separate question.