# How fast does $\lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2}\right)$ go to $\alpha$?

Tags: limits, digamma-function, euler-maclaurin, lacunary-series

In this question: [$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082380/lim-x-to-1-sum-k-0-infty-left-xk2-xk-alpha2-right) it is established that

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2}\right) = \alpha$$
 for all $\alpha > 0$.

I'd like to know how fast it approaches $\alpha$. In particular, to show that the rate of approach is such that for all $\alpha$ 
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\alpha -  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2}\right)}{1-x}$$

exists, and that when $\alpha$ is very small,

$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0^+} \left[ \lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\alpha -  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2}\right)}{1-x}
\right]=\frac16$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the same approach as in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082380/lim-x-to-1-sum-k-0-infty-left-xk2-xk-alpha2-right/2082463#2082463).  From the [Euler Maclaurin Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_formula), we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^K (x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2})&=\int_0^K (e^{y^2\log(x)}-e^{(y+\alpha)^2\log(x)})\,dy\\\\
&+\frac{e^{-K^2|\log(x)|}-e^{-(K+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}-(1-e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|})}2  \\\\
&+\frac{B_2\,\log(x)}{2!}\left(2Ke^{-K^2|\log(x)|}-2(K+\alpha)e^{-(K+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}-(0-2\alpha e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|})\right)\\\\
&+\log^2(x)\int_0^K \left(4y^2e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}-4(y+\alpha)^2e^{-(y+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}\right)P_2(y)\,dy \\\\
&=\int_0^\alpha e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}\,dy-\int_K^{K+\alpha}e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}\,dy\\\\
&+\frac{e^{-K^2|\log(x)|}-e^{-(K+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}-(1-e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|})}2  \\\\
&+\frac{\log(x)}{12}\left(2Ke^{-K^2|\log(x)|}-2(K+\alpha)e^{-(K+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}-(0-2\alpha e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|})\right)\\\\
&+\log^2(x)\int_0^K \left(4y^2e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}-4(y+\alpha)^2e^{-(y+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}\right)P_2(y)\,dy \tag 1\\\\
\end{align}$$

Letting $K\to \infty$ in $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^K (x^{k^2}-x^{(k+\alpha)^2})&=\int_0^\alpha e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}\,dy-\frac{1-e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|}}2  \\\\
&+\frac{\alpha \log(x)}{6}e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|}\\\\
&+\log^2(x)\int_0^\infty \left(4y^2e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}-4(y+\alpha)^2e^{-(y+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}\right)P_2(y)\,dy \tag 2\\\\
\end{align}$$

---

Next, we have the following limits.

**LIMIT $1$:**
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\alpha -\int_0^\alpha e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}}{1-x}=-\lim_{x\to 1^-}\int_0^\alpha \frac{y^2}{x}e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}\,dy=-\frac12\alpha^2 \tag 3$$

---

**LIMIT $2$:**
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{1-e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|}}{2(1-x)}=-\lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{\alpha^2e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|}}{2x}=-\frac12 \alpha^2 \tag 4$$

---

**LIMIT $3$:**
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{\frac{\log(x)}{6}e^{-\alpha^2|\log(x)|}}{1-x}=-\frac16 \tag 5$$

---

**LIMIT $4$:**
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{\log^2(x)}{1-x}\int_0^\infty \left(4y^2e^{-y^2|\log(x)|}-4(y+\alpha)^2e^{-(y+\alpha)^2|\log(x)|}\right)P_2(y)\,dy =0 \tag 6$$

---

Putting $(3)-(6)$ together yields the coveted limit.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you Jack!

Comment: Very nice. This reveals that for very small $\alpha$ the behavior as $\x \to 1$ is, to first order  driven by the $B_2(\log x) $ term.

Comment: Yes.  I seem to have a factor of $\alpha$ in the result (i.e., $\alpha/6$) before letting $\alpha \to 0$.  So, I don't believe that the limit as $\alpha\to 0$, as written, is $1/6$, but rather is $0$.